# Xamarin forms, how do I expose the underlying imagedata that my current code does not get?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a viewmodel that I connect to my current page where the user selects an image from his phonealbum.

When I pick a image it works perfectly fine and the picture appears on the screen just how I want but when I try to store it on my database I get a crash and I think it is (as I have been told) that it is due to the fact that my code does not get the imagedata.

Apparently there is a package called Xamarin.Plugin.Media and I have been fooling around a bit with that but with no luck.

This is my code:

My viewmodel:

```
public class CameraViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private readonly TaskScheduler _scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    private IMediaPicker _Mediapicker;
    private ImageSource _ImageSource;
    private string _VideoInfo;
    private Command _TakePictureCommand;
    private Command _SelectPictureCommand;
    private Command _SelectVideoCommand;
    private string _Status;

    public CameraViewModel()
    {
        Setup ();
    }

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return _ImageSource; }
        set { SetProperty (ref _ImageSource, value); }
    }

    public string VideoInfo
    {
        get { return _VideoInfo; }
        set { SetProperty (ref _VideoInfo, value); }
    }

    public Command TakePictureCommand
    {
        get {
            return _TakePictureCommand ?? (_TakePictureCommand =
                new Command (async () => await TakePicture (), () => true));
        }
    }

    public Command SelectPictureCommand
    {
        get {
            return _SelectPictureCommand ?? (_SelectPictureCommand =
                new Command (async () => await SelectPicture (), () => true));
        }
    }

    public Command SelectVideoCommand
    {
        get {
            return _SelectVideoCommand ?? (_SelectVideoCommand =
                new Command (async () => await SelectVideo (), () => true));
        }
    }

    public string Status
    {
        get { return _Status; }
        set { SetProperty (ref _Status, value); }
    }

    private void Setup()
    {

        if (_Mediapicker == null) {

            var device = Resolver.Resolve<IDevice> ();
            _Mediapicker = DependencyService.Get<IMediaPicker> () ?? device.MediaPicker;
        }

    }

    public async Task<MediaFile> TakePicture()
    {
        Setup ();

        ImageSource = null;

        return await _Mediapicker.TakePhotoAsync (new CameraMediaStorageOptions {
            DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front, MaxPixelDimension = 400
        }).ContinueWith (t => {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                Status = t.Exception.InnerException.ToString();
            }
            else if (t.IsCanceled)
            {
                Status = "Canceled";
            }
            else
            {
                var mediaFile = t.Result;
                ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);

                return mediaFile;
            }

            return null;
        }, _scheduler);
    }

    public async Task SelectPicture()
    {
        Setup ();

        ImageSource = null;

        try
        {
            var mediaFile = await _Mediapicker.SelectPhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions
                {
                    DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
                    MaxPixelDimension = 400
                });

            VideoInfo = mediaFile.Path;
            ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Status = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public async Task SelectVideo()
    {
        Setup ();

        VideoInfo = "Selecting video";

        try
        {
            var mediaFile =  await _Mediapicker.SelectVideoAsync(new VideoMediaStorageOptions());

            VideoInfo = mediaFile != null
                ? string.Format("Your video size {0} MB", ConvertBytesToMegabytes(mediaFile.Source.Length))
                : "No video was selected";
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is TaskCanceledException) {
                VideoInfo = "Selecting video cancelled";
            } else {
                VideoInfo = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }

    private static double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
    {
        double rtn_value = (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;

        return rtn_value;
    }
}
 }
```

the Page that i am using:

```
    CameraViewModel cameraOps = null;

    public startPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        cameraOps = new CameraViewModel ();

    }


private async void btnPickPicture_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await cameraOps.SelectPicture ();
        imgPicked.Source = cameraOps.ImageSource;

    }
```

So when I try to add my ImgPicked (Image in my XAML) in my database, it crashes. (Tell me if you would like to see the database-code as well)

And the crash says: Self referencing loop detected for property 'Member' with type 'System.Reflection.MonoMethod'. Path 'thePicture.Stream.Method.ReturnParameter'.

thePicture is where I try to store my image in my database.

Answer (score 0):

The [Media plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Media) returns a [MediaFile](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Media/Media/Media.Plugin.Abstractions/MediaFile.cs) object that has a couple of properties/methods you can use.

```
public string Path
```

is a property gives you the Path to the image file.  You can use that to read the image data with File.ReadAllBytes() or some other method.

```
public Stream GetStream()
```

is a method that returns a stream with the image data.  You can convert that stream to a byte array that will contain the image data.

You can use either of these in your ViewModel to get the byte[] data for the image, and later pass that data to your database calls.

You could modify your ViewModel to store the byte array for the image by doing something like this (untested)

```
   private byte[] imageData;

   public byte[] ImageData { get { return imageData; } }

   private byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)
   {
       byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
       using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
       {
           int read;
           while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
           {
               ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
           }
           return ms.ToArray();
       }
   }

   public async Task SelectPicture()
    {
        Setup ();

        ImageSource = null;

        try
        {
            var mediaFile = await _Mediapicker.SelectPhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions
                {
                    DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
                    MaxPixelDimension = 400
                });

            VideoInfo = mediaFile.Path;

            // store the image data in a local variable
            imageData = ReadStream(mediaFile.GetStream());

            ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Status = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which one is the easiest to implement? I am googling a bit to see how they structure the code and what to put inside the function.

Comment: Would I add the code inside  public async Task SelectPicture()?

Comment: public Stream ToStream(string path) { and add something here or like bind my image inhere?  } ?

Comment: i found this code: public Stream GetStream()
  {
   if (this.isDisposed)
    throw new ObjectDisposedException (null);

   return this.streamGetter();
  }
could I make something happen with that?the one who wrote this code uses isDisposed as a private bool .

Comment: imageData = ReadStream(mediaFile.GetStream()); // I get an error here because xamarin cannot find GetStream

Comment: I don't think you're actually using the Media plugin.  It sounds like you are still using your old code to select pics

Comment: Ah so I have to adjust my code? I thought this code that you posted would just replace my current Task SelectPicture () and that I just needed to add the package

Comment: You said that Iam using my old code but the code you posted is almost identical?

Comment: Because I assumed you had already converted your code to use the Media plugin and just needed help getting the data stream.  Believe it or not, I don't have an unlimited amount of time to help strangers on the internet debug their code.

Comment: oh i did not mean it like that, i appreciate your help alot! and then i mean alot. so i should throw away the old code then (there is no easy fix to modify the code?) and instead focus on the media plugin code?